# Advantage of Java async client when only waiting on response?

Tags: java, asynchronous

What are the advantages of using an asynchronous web client in the case that you don't want to perform any operations before waiting on the response?

Let's assume Java here, some pseudocode

```
Response response = syncClient.post(); //blocks
processResponse(response);
```

versus

```
CompletableFuture<Response> responseFuture = asyncClient.post();
Response response = responseFuture.get(); //blocks
processResponse(response);
```

I'm not doing anything other than immediately calling a blocking `get()`. Is the thread processing the response just as blocked in both cases?

Comment: None, and please don't conflate 'asynchronous' with 'non-blocking'. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: Yes. `get()` will block your thread. The asynchronous call gives you the option to not do that, but if you don't have a use for that, then there is no advantage to it.

Comment: "Is the thread handling the request just as blocked in both cases?" The thread handling the request is not getting blocked. The thread waiting for the response is.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne thanks for the reply - I don't think I'm conflating the two terms here am I? This latter snippet is both asynchronous and non-blocking right (assuming this client provided non-blocking io)?
After the request has been made, the caller thread is not blocked

Comment: No. Non-blocking means that the operation either succeeds or fails immediately. An asynchronous operation proceeds independent with a result that is fetched later. That's why you have (1) `Socket`, (2) `SocketChannel`, and (3) `AsynchronousSocketChannel`. Three modes. Not two.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne thanks for the reply. I still don't see why this is not either asynchronous or non-blocking, could you explain specifically why? 
`Non-blocking means that the operation either succeeds or fails immediately. An asynchronous operation proceeds independent with a result that is fetched later`
The `post()` operation returns a future immediately, and the caller thread is freed up to do whatever until calling `get()` to retrieve the result.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for the reply - in this case, I was imagining that the code blocks I posted were executing in a request-handling thread as part of a service A. The service is making a call to another web service B here. I was referring to A's request-handling thread waiting on a response from B. I'll reword my question to be more clear

Comment: I didn't say it was neither asynchronous nor non-blocking. I said it was asynchronous, which means it is neither blocking or non-blocking. The `post()` operation returns a future from which you can retrieve the result at some future time, exactly as I stated above. The point is that the operation continues after the API returns, unlike both blocking and non-blocking I/O, where the operation is complete at that point, with either a success or a failure. I was really commenting on your use of the [tag:non-blocking] tag, which is irrelevant for the reasons  I've stated.

Answer (score 0):

If your application that is making the call has nothing to do and is not multithreaded then there is not much of an advantage.

But in a traditional multithreaded application using asynchronous (or non-blocking) requests allows for the sharing of a single thread so that you can actually avoid creating multiple threads.  For example, let's say you have 10 streams of code running at the same time.  Traditionally one would create 10 separate threads.  But if all your threads are making non-blocking calls, you can run all 10 streams in 1 thread.  Whenever a traditionally blocking request is made (calling an API or calling a DB), instead of waiting there, you can pass it the code for what to do when it's complete, allowing the 10 streams to be processed in 1 thread.  IMHO this is the main use case of non-blocking code.  Not so much having your one stream do other things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jose. Following your example, if we have this one thread handling these 10 requests, and we have tasks to execute to process each response, won't we need 10 threads anyway to individually handle processing those responses in parallel (let's assume they all finish at the same time)? So in fact, we now have 11 threads instead of 10 if we just had made 10 threads to handle making and processing the requests?

Comment: Processing those responses can happen in one thread as long as the processing of the responses do not have blocking calls.  You save CPU resources by processing them in one thread because you avoid context switching.  When a CPU switches from 1 thread to another it goes through the process of context switching, which takes time (nanoseconds).  To process the 10 stream in 1 thread, at every blocking request, you pass the lambda or callback for how to continue.  This is the basis of reactive coding used now in many languages including Java.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but ultimately if we want to simultaneously process all 10 responses, you'll need to do it in multiple threads right? Assuming processing these responses is not an IO task and is a CPU bound task (as business logic processing responses typically is), the only way to parallelize this workload is via threading. Otherwise, it's being done synchronously and we are wasting wall time.

Comment: Not really.  One CPU processes one command at a time.  It looks like it is doing them at the same time, but only one instruction at a time.  It just does it very fast.  By keeping the 10 streams in one thread you save your CPU the trouble of switching contexts.

Comment: Of course if you have two CPU, or two cores, then you can do 2 at a time.  Then there is hyper-threading.  But you have to limit yourself to number of cores and also manage affinity, to ensure that your two threads (assuming a 2 core CPU) are not running on the same core.

Comment: You say "Not really" but I think you are actually agreeing with me. I think we agree that the only way to do those ten tasks in parallel (not just concurrently), is with 10 different threads and at least that many cores to support.